# Is it possible to see where a .DLL is searching for a file?

Tags: c#, dll, resources

I get a "File not found." message from a .DLL I am using, but I am not sure which path it tries to find the file in. It might as well be hard-coded, and I would like to find out.

Is there any method or tool I could use?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is this your dll, or a third party component that you don't have access to its source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) will do this out-of-the-box for you. Download, unzip and run the exe file. It should immediately show you which processes are trying to access which files.

To apply a filter, hit Ctrl+L (or click the 'Filter' icon in the top menu). Then choose "Process Name is xxx" where xxx is the name of your process. Then click "Add", and then "Ok". This will filter to just your process.

You can also use Find (Ctrl+F) to find things.

Another tip, stop and start capturing by clicking Ctrl+E.

Comment: Process Monitor is better than Process Explorer for identifying file access - this is a better answer than mine.

Comment: This answer would be better if it included instructions on how to use the filtering in Process Monitor, as by default it produces a lot of output.

Comment: Agreed with Polyfun, but indeed this tool was more useful in my case. 
Thank you all for your answers, I can take it from here. Have a great day!

Comment: Have added some tips to filter results.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [Process Explorer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx). From the page:

> Ever wondered which program has a particular file or directory open?
>   Now you can find out. Process Explorer shows you information about
>   which handles and DLLs processes have opened or loaded.

If you hit `Ctrl + D` (show DLL view - can also be done from View menu) and then select your process, it will show all of the DLLs loaded by that process and their locations.

You may also get useful answers asking in [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites. With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming."

https://stackoverflow.com/tour

I think it qualifies.

Comment: You are asking for a recommendation for software - I just wanted to let you know that you may get better answers at software recommendation site, and that I have seen many questions like this get closed as "off topic".

Comment: Yes, and thank you for you answer, although I am looking for a method or tool, I am not certainly looking for software as I don't know what the solution would be. It could be that I can debug it or see it in visual studio or call a command that extensively debugs it when I load it.

Comment: I've just checked the FAQ and it says "software tools commonly used by programmers;" - so I withdraw my point about being off topic :)

Comment: Thank you for correcting the response. I am trying this tool, it seems very helpful, but it shoes me what files are trying to be accessed, not which location the process is trying to look into. I think if the file doesn't exist, it would not detect it. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Your link to Process Explorer is broken.

Comment: @Sindorej I've updated my answer to say how to show the DLL view in Process Explorer. However, I believe now that cbp's answer is actually better - Process Monitor will be more useful.

Comment: @Polyfun Fixed. I think I did a bad paste :(

Answer (score 1):

See here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/suzcook/2003/05/29/debugging-assembly-loading-failures/

May be it is a problem installing the DLL in the GAC.

a Tool like Reshaper gives more information in these situations, you can try also http://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the DLL is loading fine, it just tries to find a configuration file that doesn't exist (at the place where it's looking).

Comment: You're welcome. :)  Try Resharper then, it fixes dependencies problems. use trial version.